# How to set a style to parts of a document

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, find, variant

I've got a function which sets a style to headings in a book. I'm trying to apply different style to other parts of the document, but can't quite get it working.

So there's 3 styles:

1. Chapter heading
2. First line of text after the chapter heading up to the next line break (^p)
3. Everything after the first line, up to the next page break (^m)

I'm sure I declare to other arrays using wildcards - but am having difficulty with the logic, and have had issues when wildcards = true.

If anyone also happens to have any resources on how to set your own styles then declare them to each part (see the replacement style in the code for an idea as to what I want to do - "Heading 1,Chapter Heading" - can I define that in the macro?), i'd really appreciate it!

See code below for the Chapter function.

```
Private Function iiiChapterHeadings()
    Dim Chapters As Variant, Chapter
    Chapters = Array("Chapter One", "Chapter Two", "Chapter Three")

    For Each Chapter In Chapters

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles( _
        "Heading 1,Chapter Heading")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = Chapter
        .Replacement.Text = "^m" & Chapter & "^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next

End Function
```

EXAMPLE OF A DOCUMENT!!!!

```
Chapter One^p
^p
This first line of text will have a style set to it so there's no indentation, the first letter of the sentence is a capital letter and it applies to everything up to the next line break.^p
Everything after the line break above has a different style set to it.^p
All of this will have that style up until the next page break.^p
As will this line.^p
And this etc. ^p
^m

Chapter Two^p
^p
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wildcards for this. An ordinary Find with a loop will do. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range
    .Style = wdStyleNormal
    .InsertBefore vbCr
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "^pChapter"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      .Start = .Start + 1
      .Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading1
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .Text = ""
      .Style = wdStyleHeading1
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      .Paragraphs.First.Next.Style = wdStyleHeading2
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
  .Range.Characters.First.Text = vbNullString
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above code assumes the bulk of the text will be in the 'Normal' Style, whilst your Chapter headings will employ the 'Heading 1' Style and the paragraphs following those will employ the 'Heading 2' Style. Since you don't say what Styles you're using other than 'Heading 1', I've simply picked two built-in Styles.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly your document contains a number of chapters separated by manual page breaks. The chapter headings consist of "Chapter " and one other word and are followed by an empty paragraph.

In your question you refer to "line break (^p)". Be careful not to confuse lines with paragraphs as they are different. ^p is actually a paragraph mark and is entered using the `Enter` key. There are also manual line line breaks in Word, entered using `Shift+Enter`, which are found using ^l.

If the only purpose of the page break is to ensure that the chapter heading is on a new page it is unnecessary. Your chapter heading style can be defined to have an implicit page break by setting 'Page break before'.

The empty paragraph after the chapter heading is also unnecessary. The need for that method of spacing died with the typewriter. Instead set the 'Spacing after' for your chapter heading style to provide an appropriate amount of space.

Word's built-in styles, with the exception of Normal, all have names that describe their intended use. The most appropriate style for the text in the body of your document is Body Text.

As Word's built-in style names change to reflect the application language it is best to use the WdBuiltinStyle enumerator when referring to them. There is a value for most styles though the most recently added ones are missing.

The code below does all of the above and uses a wildcard search to avoid adding anything extra to the document.

```
Sub FormatDocument()
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    'set base style for document
    .Style = wdStyleBodyText
    RemovePageBreaks
    ModifyHeading1
    ' Find chapter headings and apply Heading 1
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = "Chapter <*>"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With

    Do While .Find.Found
      With .Paragraphs.First
        .Style = wdStyleHeading1
        .Next.Style = wdStyleHeading2
      End With
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub RemovePageBreaks()
  With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^m"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    'removing the page break leaves an empty para so remove all empty paragraphs
    'this will also remove the unnecessary empty paragraph after the chapter heading
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^p^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub ModifyHeading1()
  With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).ParagraphFormat
    'add implicit page break
    .PageBreakBefore = True
    'add space after in points
    .SpaceAfter = 12
  End With
End Sub
```

If you want to learn more about styles in Word pay a visit to [Shauna Kelly's website](https://shaunakelly.com/)

Although a lot of the articles it contains are rather old you might also find the site for the [Word MVP's](https://wordmvp.com/) useful. It also contains links to the websites of the individual MVP's.

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back m4o_tim.

Sorry for the late reply, if I could have a few days to get everything together and try this out, would it be alright if I got back in touch if I have any problems? I suspect I might have issues setting the first line of text with a style, and the rest of the body with another.

Please let me know!

Comment: So long as the “first line” is an entire paragraph, as your question suggests, you won’t have any issues.